# ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); is undefined in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, activex

Here I am trying to call system calculator using ActiveXObject. In IE it is working fine for me but in Firefox it is not coming. I am getting the Undefined error. How to solve this problem in Firefox?

```
try{
    if(gBrowser == 'IE'){
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");  
        shell.Run("calc"); 
    }
    else{
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");  
        shell.Run("calc",1,true); 
    }
}
catch(e){
    if(gBrowser == 'IE'){
        alert(e.description);
    }
    else{
        alert(e.description);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.ActiveX is a proprietary technology only supported by Microsoft and for that IE supports it, Firefox doesn't support `ActiveXObject`, and it can't access the shell object either.
 You can create COM components in FF, but it requires a plugin and some definite effort.Probably not a solution in this case.

Firefox does not support ActiveX technology for multiple reasons.

- ActiveX is only available on Windows operating systems, and as a
  result webpages that require it will not work on Linux or Mac.
- ActiveX integration with the Windows operating system has made
  it a target for malicious software.

Comment: do not use ActiveXObject when the browser is not equal IE.    You got my point?

Comment: For cross browser solution, use object element instead. Read more about it visit http://help.dottoro.com/ljcnpkfv.php